# How can I remove the little white insects from semolina and flour?

Tags: food-safety, food-science, cleaning, flour

Sometimes I feel that little white insects seem in flour and semolina , specially in rainy season. The flour and semolina attacked  these insects can be used ? If yes then how can I remove these insects from flour and semolina ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One I've never tried - nor needed to, I live in a temperate zone...

My aunt lived in Singapore for many years - she would put anything like that, flour or even sugar, into a tin then put the tin on a low heat on the gas & the insects would climb out & fall into the flame.

Flour can of course be sieved too, semolina may depend on how fine it is.